# Obfuscate an email inside a string using react-obfuscate-email

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a string that contains, among other text, an email address. I'd like to obfuscate the address using [`react-obfuscate-email`](https://github.com/MauricioRobayo/react-obfuscate-email), but every option I tried doesn't work, as it either returns the literal email address or `[object Object]`.

This is my last attempt, but other than not replacing the string it wipes portions of the string.

```js
import React from "react";
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
import { Email } from "react-obfuscate-email";
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

function Address({agency}) {
    // Split the string in spaces and loop through the array, add an if if the portion matches an email address patternt
    const parsedAddress = agency.address.split(' ').map((word) => {
        if (word.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/g)) {
            return <Email email={word} />;
        }
        return word;
    }).join(' ');

    return (
        <div className="Address">
            <div className="name mb-3">{agency.company}</div>
            <div className="country mb-4">{agency.country}</div>
            <div className="text mt-3 email">{parse(parsedAddress)}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Address;
```

This version displays the email address but fails to render the JS portion that initially obfuscates it, so it's rendered clear from the beginning.

```js
import React from "react";
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
import { Email } from "react-obfuscate-email";
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

function Address({agency}) {
    // Manually create the obfuscated email link
    const obfuscatedAddress = agency.address.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/g, (match) => {
        const emailComponent = <Email email={match} />;
        return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(emailComponent);
    });

    // Parse the obfuscated address containing HTML strings
    const parsedAddress = parse(obfuscatedAddress);

    return (
        <div className="Address">
            <div className="name mb-3">{agency.company}</div>
            <div className="country mb-4">{agency.country}</div>
            <div className="text mt-3 email">{parsedAddress}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Address;
```

Is it possible to make it work?